# I need to organize my classes in a way that the constructor can be called from a loop

Tags: c++, class, polymorphism

This is going to be hard to explain so let me use an example:

Imagine you have 10 items on a GUI that are all inheriting members from the same abstract base class. You want to be able to use a loop to check if the user clicked on any of the items. Then you want to be able to call a constructor from that item. The essence of this is that pointers point to objects but I am asking if It is possible to have them point to the actual class or do something with a similar function. Seeing as this explanation could seem a little bit confusing allow me to elaborate with code.

This example will use 3 Items rather than 10 for simplicity

```
class A //the base class
{
public:
    int x,y;// inherited values
    virtual void render() = 0;// thats right its an abstract class
};
A * basePointer = NULL;


class a0: public A
{
public:
    a0()
    {
        //do stuff
    }
    void render()
    {
        //do render stuff
    }
}

class a1: public A
{
public:
    a1()
    {
        //do different stuff
    }
    void render()
    {
        //do different render stuff
    }
}

class a2: public A
{
public:
    a2()
    {
        //do even more stuff
    }
    void render()
    {
        //do even more render stuff
    }
}



mainloop()
{
    //handle events and get mouse position
    for(int i = 0;i < 3;i++)//3 being the number of non-absract classes
    {
        if(a[i].x = mousePos.x && a[i].y = mousePos.y)
        {
            basePointer = new a[i]
        }
    }
}
```

I understand that trying to reference a1,a2, and a3 using a[i] and a loop was kind of silly but I hope It helps you understand what I am trying to do. Any help help or work around suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Alf Sorry I did my best to make it clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical way of achieving this is called "**Cloning**", or another form of the [Factory design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

You could add a `Clone` pure virtual method in the Base class, allowing each object to clone itself.

```
class A //the base class
{
public:
    int x,y;// inherited values
    virtual void render() = 0;// thats right its an abstract class
    virtual std::unique_ptr<A> Clone() = 0;
};
```

A typical override is quite simple :

```
//In class a1
virtual std::unique_ptr<A> Clone()
{
    auto clone = new a1();
    clone->x = x;
    clone->y = y;
    return std::unique_ptr<A>(clone);
}
```

Writing a for loop to render and duplicate objects is then trivial :

```
std::vector<A*> items;
items.push_back(new a0 ());
items.push_back(new a1 ());
items.push_back(new a2 ());

for(auto item : items)
{
    item->render();
    auto new_item = item->Clone();
    // use the clone
}
```

Live example on [ideone](http://ideone.com/cA2NCr).